# How can I avoid dropdownlist to NOT modify data if I don't select anything using Ajax - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have page with a `Textarea` and a `DropDownList` and both of them going Send/Save Value into database when I hit the submit button but when I write something in `Textarea` and I don't select value from `dropdownlist` and then when I check database I can see in database that Column which contains data for `Dropdownlist` its going modified with 0 value.

My question is how can I avoid `dropdownlist` to NOT modify data if I dont select anything for example something like (if selected value == 0 or if selected value == "" - Don't modify data and do not send/save into database) and modify data just for `Textarea`.

*PS I can avoid dropdownlist to NOT modified data , using Validation but than I can't send modified Value just for `Textarea`.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RMADropDownEdit(VMRMA model, int? id, string Kommenter)
{

    var s = db.RMA_History.Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (s != null)
    {    
            //DropDown
            s.StatusID = model.SelectedStatus;
            //Textare
            s.Kommenter = Kommenter;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }


        return Json(s, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

View:

```
<form id="FormRMA">

<div class="form-group">

<label class="form-control-label">Write your Comment:</label>  
<textarea class="form-control" name="Kommenter" id="Kommenter" cols="40" rows="5">
</textarea>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-control-label">Update status</label>
   <br />

@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.SelectedStatus, Model.Status, "- Select -", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectedStatus" })

 </div>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="@Model.HRMAs.Id" class="form-control">

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" id="submitRMA" class="btn btn-primary">Send Data</button>
</div>

</form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#FormRMA").submit(function (e) {


            var model = {

                SelectedStatus: $("#SelectedStatus").val(),
                Kommenter: $("#Kommenter").val(),
                id : $("#id").val()

            }


            e.preventDefault();



            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/xxx/RMADropDownEdit",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                success: function (run) {

                    if (!$.trim(run)) {
                        alert("What follows is blank: ");
                    }
                    else {
                        run.StatusID = model.SelectedStatus;

                        run.Kommenter = Kommenter;



                     swal({ title: "Good job", text: "You clicked the button!", type: "success" },
                     function () 
                     {
                         location.reload();
                     },3000);


                    }


                },



            });

        });


    });
</script>
```

HTML Markup:

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="SelectedStatus" name="SelectedStatus">
<option value="">- Select -</option>
<option value="1">Sendt</option>
<option value="2">Under behandling</option>
<option value="3">Blive behandlet</option>
<option value="4">Modtaget</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the value of `model.SelectedStatus` when nothing is selected from the dropdown? and when you set a break point on it?

Comment: @Izzy value is 0 when nothing is selected

Comment: isn't the dropdownlist already populated with the existing value? In that case all the user has to do is leave it alone and it will send the same value back to the server when the form is submitted.

Comment: @ADyson yes it is , if i leave everything alone ,and than i checked database it will send 0 value to dat column Contains for DropDown and Send nothing empty to dat column Contains for Textarea and than i hit the submit button in page i will get this error > object reference not set to an instance of an object and its beacuse dat column Contains data for textarea is totally empty and the reason idont want update drop down when i dont selected its beause  value of status is 0 , and its going show to customer. and you know its not nice

Comment: @ADyson and the an other reason our employee should updated status in system what if they dont want update status but want write a Comment

Comment: if it's already populated with a valid existing value from the model, then how can it be sending back 0?  That makes no sense. It would send back the value already pre-selected in the dropdown. The only options available in your dropdown should be ones which are valid to enter into the database. Of course you can also have a "None" option which means select nothing, in that case the value of that option should be "" and this should cause NULL to be inserted into the database, which will also be a valid state.

Comment: "what if they dont want update status"...then they should leave the status set to the value which MVC sets it to when the page loads...which should be the `SelectedStatus` value from the model. If you are not setting this model value correctly, then should change your code do to so.

Comment: Yes i know , and beacuse <option value="">- Select -</option> has been selected when u going to page ,and if we cant see selected attr in html markup , i think its beacuse DropdownListfor or i should Enabled in my controller. but i get what u mean.

Comment: "beacuse <option value="">- Select -</option> has been selected when u going to page"...if this is happening despite there being an existing, valid value in the database for this field, then this implies that `Model.SelectedStatus` is not set correctly. You need to debug that, I think.

Comment: @ADyson  the things your saying its correct , im I agree with you and i chenged the code , i just remove this "- Select -" for dropdownlistfor , and its going to show selected item and the question i asked , i had both which is drop down have nice text for employee and data dont get modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a simple `if` condition as follows:

```
if(model.SelectedStatus != 0)
    s.StatusID = model.SelectedStatus;
```

The above snippet is assuming the datatype of `SelectedStatus` is of `int`

If the datatype of `SelectedStatus` is of `string` then you'll have to do the following and you can also check if the string is null or empty:

```
if(model.SelectedStatus != "0" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SelectedStatus))
    s.StatusID = model.SelectedStatus;
```

Comment: datatype of  SelectedStatus  its int , and let me try just sec :)